# Adding a VB file into a C# project

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am currently trying to add a VB file inside a C# project, but I am only able to add C# files. Is there a way for me to be able to add more language templates like what is shown below?

This picture below is an example of what I have been able to do in an old project which is to be able to add both VB and C# files into one project.
[image: Example]

**Update**: I am redeveloping an ASP.NET 2.0 site to the newest version with the new bootstrap framework. I didn't realize the old project was using mostly VB until I started the redevelopment in C#. I noticed that the old project is also using some C#. I am trying to see if I can have those two languages inside a new ASP.NET project or not by adding VB files. If not, I'll just make a VB project and convert all of the C# code to it.

Comment: You cannot add a VB.NET file to a C# project, they are two different languages, it is like asking if I can add this Java file to my C++ Project. You can reference a compiled VB.NET dll in a C# project, but not the uncompiled source.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Since Visual Studio does not support compiling both VB and C# files in the same project, I'd be curious to know the point of this.

Comment: Keep the vb code in its own project, add that to your solution and create a project reference to it in your c# project. More information is needed in regards to what your VB code is doing to answer in any more detail

Comment: My guess is that the aspx files have `CodeFile` attribute, which compiles the source on the fly, rather than precompiled assembly with the `CodeBehind` attribute. First option could potentially allow a mix of c# and vb.

Comment: The first option you said is inside the old project and that does make more sense as to what that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open the "Add new file" dialog inside a project, it is filtered by the current project type you're working on. E.g. you cannot add a *.vb file to a C# project type, without hacking it somehow.

The GUID within the *.csproj file defines the current project type. [This site contains a set of known GUIDs](http://www.mztools.com/Articles/2008/MZ2008017.aspx), it is somewhat outdated since it's from 2008.

As I said in a comment, the reason you have been able to mix-in both VB and C# code within the web project, is by using `CodeFile` attribute, rather than the `CodeBehind` attribute. The latter will compile all the source files within the project into an assembly with the same name. This will be the file you are uplading to your webserver along with the `.aspx` files.

**Sample file structure:**

```
bin/MyApp.MyProject.dll
Index.aspx
```

The `CodeFile` variant, which compiles the source on the fly will need all the files in the same directory, or in the directory specified within the attribute, for this example it will reside within the same directory. This will also allow you to change the code at the web server, and not having to download the code to your development environment. (This is NOT recommended, as you wave goodbye to any version control and other useful tools.)

**Sample file structure:**

```
Index.aspx
Index.aspx.cs
```

My advice would be to decide whether or not to continue developing in VB, or switch to C#. Containing your codebase to one language is preferrable. And if you decide to refactor the whole solution, why not give ASP.NET MVC a go? :-)

Comment: I have decided to give up on trying to make a multi-language project and just decided to work on just C#. I am taking your advice and going to use ASP.NET MVC. I am pretty new to MVC, but it is pretty sweet! Thank you for your detailed answer as to why it can't happen.

Comment: It sure is. You've made a great choice, and I hope you'll like it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually there used to be, not sure if it's still available, to put a VB file in a C# project. You would have needed to add a text file type but name it with a .vb extension. Then place it in a folder. Then in the app or web config, you needed to add some config to tell the runtime where to find the vb files and to use VB compiler to compile the code.

It worked but was clunky and not recommended. Again, not sure if it's available anymore.

Personally, if you have VB code, use a vb2cs converter like [this one](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) to begin converting it over. They are not perfect but it's at least a good start in most cases.

Comment: -1: this doesn't really answer the question, especially since I believe you're thinking about an ASP.NET solution.

Comment: As I said, not recommended and OP didn't exactly specify what type of project. I gave an alternative solution for possibly getting the code they need into the project, which was to convert it.

Comment: I appreciate the alternative method and I am considering that option if all else fails.